# How to specify "max-loop" option for Clang Tidy?

Tags: clang-tidy

I'm trying this, but doesn't work:

```
$ clang-tidy --config="analyzer-max-loop: 10" a.cpp --
<command-line-config>:1:1: error: unknown key 'analyzer-max-loop'
analyzer-max-loop: 10
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: invalid configuration specified.
Invalid argument
```

I want the analyzer to try to iterate through a loop 10 times.

Comment: Where have you got it from? `analyzer-max-loop` is not a clang-tidy's key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works:

```
$ clang --analyze -Xclang -analyzer-constraints=z3 \
  -Xclang -analyzer-max-loop -Xclang 10 a.cpp
```

Comment: The question specified `clang-tidy`, but this answer is for `clang --analyze`.  And did setting this option have any observable effect?

Comment: Yes, thanks to this setting clang Clang-TIdy/CSA/Clang (I'm lost) can find a bug in a loop that iterates for more than four times.